# Distributed search using groups in Solr

Tags: solr, grouping, distributed

I have Solr shards splited by date.

A specific data can be on more than 1 shard. I want group the data to have distinct elements between different shards.

Imagine that I do a distributed search between 3 shards finding a url 'http://a.com', the 3 shards have the url.

My problem is that the group.ngroups result of distributed search is not that I expected. I have 3 different groups, but I only want 1.

The question is, is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Generally if there's no specific features in the DBMS product this issue is being solved by introducing temporary table with intermediate results of each shard and by applying additional grouping on this temp table.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot say that I'm using Solr 4.0 not a common DBMS